# Would compiler secretly increase struct's alignment?

Tags: c++, c, struct, memory-alignment

I have a struct of 8-bytes alignment, but when I define some variables of this type continuously but not in an array, it seems to be 16-bytes alignment. My question is, does the compiler increase its alignment for some purpose?

My test code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
struct a{
    long l[3];
};

struct a a1;
struct a a2;
struct a a3;

int main(){
    printf("%lx\n", (uintptr_t)&a1);
    printf("%lx\n", (uintptr_t)&a2);
    printf("%lx\n", (uintptr_t)&a3);
    return 0;
}
```

And the output is:

```
601030
601050
601070
```

Comment: Depending on the actual type of `uintptr_t`: undefined behaviour. Anything can happen. And printing the value of a pointer converted to an integer is not defined by the standard. Comparing pointers which don't point to (or exactly past) an object/array is also UB. Your value don't show anything relevant. The only interesting question is: What does `_Alignof(struct a)` yield?

Comment: Since they aren't in array compiler is free to put them in any order and with some extra empty space (or other unrelated data) in between them.

Comment: Have you printed `sizeof(struct a)`?  Have you considered using `printf("%" PRIXPTR "\n", (uintptr_t)(void *)&a1);` and including `#include <inttypes.h>`, which would conform to the standard requirements better.  But you might get away with what you're doing.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Why not print the pointer value directly? If there is `stdint.h`, there should also be `%p`.

Comment: @Olaf: Up to you; you can do that.  I don't like what `%p` produces on the platforms I use, so I don't use it all that often.  The code was using `uintptr_t`, so formatting it correctly would be better.  I usually use a format more like `"0x%" PRIXPTR`, possibly with a length.

Comment: @Olaf Conversion of pointer to `uintptr_t` is well defined and there is nothing wrong with printing the value of any integer. The code posted does not compare pointers at all.

Comment: A `long` is (typically, not always) size and alignment of 4 bytes. Your claim that the struct has an alignment of `8` is spurious.    A `struct` containing three `long` will be aligned on a multiple of 4 that is *at least* 3.   i.e. a minimum of 12.   Compilers often aim for a multiple that is even (or, sometimes, a power of two) since memory accesses in hardware tend to be optimised that way, which would mean an alignment of at least `16`.

Comment: @Peter: If the compiler is 32-bit, or you're working on Windows 64, then your observation is more or less accurate.  If you're working on 64-bit Unix, then `long` is normally an 8-byte quantity.

Comment: @Jonathan - in which case, the compiler may well align such a struct as (a multiple of) 24 or 32, by the same logic.    The example given by the OP suggests a 32-bit compiler (or, at least, one with a 4-byte `long`).

Comment: Hi, I forget to say the environment is 64-bit,  `sizeof(struct a)`  returns 24 and `__alignof__(struct a)`  return 8...

Comment: @VTT: Wrong: The conversion is not defined by the standard, but implementation defined. For `uintptr_t`, the standard only guarantees "… that any valid pointer to void can be converted to this type, then converted back to pointer to void, and the result will compare equal to the original pointer: …". It does not say anything about printing the value. And while the code does not compare, OP does apparently; it is the core of the question. The standard does not say where the comparison is performed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On a 64-bit Unix machine (a Mac running macOS Sierra 10.12.6, using GCC 7.1.0), this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
struct a
{
    long l[3];
};

struct a a1;
struct a a2;
struct a a3;
struct a a4[4];

int main(void)
{
    printf("sizeof(struct a) = %zu\n", sizeof(struct a));
    printf("a1 = 0x%.16" PRIXPTR "\n", (uintptr_t)(void *)&a1);
    printf("a2 = 0x%.16" PRIXPTR "\n", (uintptr_t)(void *)&a2);
    printf("a3 = 0x%.16" PRIXPTR "\n", (uintptr_t)(void *)&a3);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        printf("a4[%d] = 0x%.16" PRIXPTR "\n", i, (uintptr_t)(void *)&a4[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

produces this result:

```
sizeof(struct a) = 24
a1 = 0x0000000106776020
a2 = 0x0000000106776040
a3 = 0x0000000106776060
a4[0] = 0x0000000106776080
a4[1] = 0x0000000106776098
a4[2] = 0x00000001067760B0
a4[3] = 0x00000001067760C8
```

Note that the three standalone structures are laid out on 32-byte boundaries, but those in the array are laid out on 24-byte boundaries, as would be expected given the size of the structure (24 bytes).

By contrast (and contrary to an earlier edition of this answer), compiling with Clang (`Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)`), produces the result:

```
sizeof(struct a) = 24
a1 = 0x0000000102ACE020
a2 = 0x0000000102ACE038
a3 = 0x0000000102ACE050
a4[0] = 0x0000000102ACE070
a4[1] = 0x0000000102ACE088
a4[2] = 0x0000000102ACE0A0
a4[3] = 0x0000000102ACE0B8
```

Note that the single structures are now laid out on 24-byte boundaries (or, at least, 24 bytes apart instead of 32 as with GCC).

I don't have an explanation for why GCC adds the space, but 
the compiler is perfectly at liberty to do so.
Both compilers are correct — the result is simply different.

Comment: The placement of global objects in memory is more related to the link loader (`ld`) and possibly to the OS specific process loading mechanism.  The compilers might also flag the objects with different specific alignment (32 byte vs 8 byte).